# Parse function not defined

Tags: parsing, haskell, programming-pearls

I am [following the following paper](https://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Espsuresh/teaching/prgh15/papers/monadic-parsing.pdf) and struggling to implement. The code does not mention the implementation of `parse` or `ord`. I tried to do it without implementing Prelude, but this is my next exercise, hence the comment at the top.

My code is as follows, copying directly from the Paper:

```
{- {-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

type String :: *
type String = [ Char ]

type Char :: *
data Char = GHC.Types.C# GHC.Prim.Char#
-}

newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser (\cs -> case cs of
    ""     -> []
    (c:cs) -> [(c,cs)])

class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

instance Main.Monad Parser where
      return a = Parser (\cs -> [(a,cs)])
      (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
      p >>= f  = Parser (\cs -> concat [parse (f a) cs' |
                                   (a,cs') <- parse p cs])

p :: Parser (Char,Char)
p  = do {c <- item; item; d <- item; Main.return (c,d)}

class Main.Monad m => MonadZero m where
      zero :: m a

class MonadZero m => MonadPlus m where
    (++) :: m a -> m a -> m a

instance MonadZero Parser where
      zero :: Parser a
      zero   = Parser (\cs -> [])

instance MonadPlus Parser where
      p ++ q = Parser (\cs -> parse p cs Main.++ parse q cs)

(+++)  :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p +++ q = Parser (\cs -> case parse (p Main.++ q) cs of
                               []     -> []
                               (x:xs) -> [x])

sat  :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do {c <- item; if p c then Main.return c else zero}

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = sat (c ==)

string       :: String -> Parser String
string ""     = Main.return ""
string (c:cs) = do {char c; string cs; Main.return (c:cs)}

many   :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many p  = many1 p +++ Main.return []

many1  :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many1 p = do {a <- p; as <- many p; Main.return (a:as)}

sepby         :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser [a]
p `sepby` sep  = (p `sepby1` sep) +++ Main.return []

sepby1 :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser [a] 
p `sepby1` sep = do a <-p
                    as <- many (do {sep; p})
                    Main.return (a:as)

chainl :: Parser a -> Parser (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Parser a 
chainl p op a = (p `chainl1` op) +++ Main.return a

chainl1 :: Parser a -> Parser (a -> a -> a) -> Parser a
p `chainl1` op = do {a <- p; rest a}
                    where
                       rest a = (do f <- op
                                    b <- p
                                    rest (f a b))
                                +++ Main.return a

space :: Parser String
space = many (sat isSpace)

token  :: Parser a -> Parser a
token p = do {a <- p; space; Main.return a}

symb :: String -> Parser String
symb cs = token (string cs)

apply  :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
apply p = parse (do {space; p})

expr  :: Parser Int
addop :: Parser (Int -> Int -> Int)
mulop :: Parser (Int -> Int -> Int)

expr = term `chainl1` addop
term = factor `chainl1` mulop
factor = digit +++ do {symb "("; n <- expr; symb ")"; Main.return n}
digit = do {x <- token (sat isDigit); Main.return (ord x - ord '0')}

addop = do {symb "+"; Main.return (+)} +++ do {symb "-"; Main.return (-)}
mulop = do {symb "*"; Main.return (*)} +++ do {symb "/"; Main.return (div)}
```

The problem is that the `parse` function is not defined anywhere, and when trying to compile using GHCi, I get the following error:

```
GHCi, version 9.4.8: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs, interpreted )

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:24:41: error:
    Variable not in scope: parse :: Parser b -> t0 -> [(b, String)]
   |
24 |       p >>= f  = Parser (\cs -> concat [parse (f a) cs' |
   |                                         ^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:25:47: error:
    Variable not in scope: parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, t0)]
   |
25 |                                    (a,cs') <- parse p cs])
   |                                               ^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:41:31: error:
    Variable not in scope: parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
   |
41 |       p ++ q = Parser (\cs -> parse p cs Main.++ parse q cs)
   |                               ^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:41:50: error:
    Variable not in scope: parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
   |
41 |       p ++ q = Parser (\cs -> parse p cs Main.++ parse q cs)
   |                                                  ^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:44:31: error:
    Variable not in scope: parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
   |
44 | p +++ q = Parser (\cs -> case parse (p Main.++ q) cs of
   |                               ^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:84:19: error:
    Variable not in scope: isSpace :: Char -> Bool
    Suggested fix: Perhaps use ‘space’ (line 84)
   |
84 | space = many (sat isSpace)
   |                   ^^^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:93:11: error:
    Variable not in scope: parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
   |
93 | apply p = parse (do {space; p})
   |           ^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:102:29: error:
    Variable not in scope: isDigit :: Char -> Bool
    |
102 | digit = do {x <- token (sat isDigit); Main.return (ord x - ord '0')}
    |                             ^^^^^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:102:52: error:
    Variable not in scope: ord :: Char -> b
    Suggested fix:
      Perhaps use one of these:
        ‘or’ (imported from Prelude), ‘odd’ (imported from Prelude)
    |
102 | digit = do {x <- token (sat isDigit); Main.return (ord x - ord '0')}
    |                                                    ^^^

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:102:60: error:
    Variable not in scope: ord :: Char -> b
    Suggested fix:
      Perhaps use one of these:
        ‘or’ (imported from Prelude), ‘odd’ (imported from Prelude)
    |
102 | digit = do {x <- token (sat isDigit); Main.return (ord x - ord '0')}
    |                                                            ^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I have tried to get the code from the paper to compile but had no luck. I think I need to define the `parse` and `ord` functions myself, but I'm not sure if I am have just implemented the code incorrectly -- I am almost certain I haven't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parse` is in fact defined in the paper on page 438. It's also guessable from the type signature GHC tells you it should have.

```
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse (Parser p) = p
```

`ord` and `isSpace` are in `Data.Char`.

Other notes: Please avoid reimplementing language primitives (like `Char`) in real code. By convention, anything with a `#` in its name is to be considered "low-level" and an implementation detail, can't even be named without the `MagicHash` extension, and should not be touched in >90% of cases. `NoImplicitPrelude` is not useful except in the very rare case that you want to avoid importing *instances* from `Prelude`. Otherwise a simple (and standard!) `import Prelude()` causes all names from `Prelude` to be out of scope. You add individual names to the import list instead of reimplementing stuff that you really shouldn't. Also, `*` as a kind is obsolete and should be replaced with `Data.Kind.Type`

Comment: The main problem now is that this error occurs:```GHCi, version 9.4.8: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling MonadicParsingInHaskell ( MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs, interpreted )

MonadicParsingInHaskell.hs:13:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
13 | newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])
   | ^
Failed, no modules loaded.``` That is, the ```newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])``` isn't compiling.